# How do I refresh the data in the ListView?(json&http)

Tags: android, json, http, android-listview, response

First of all , there is a listview in the activity named "user" . In the activity class, I have a thread that runs every 10 seconds. The thread calls a function which executes an AsyncTask . The AsyncTask does an http request and the response is parsed by a class named JSONparse . The data is then used in a listview inside a for loopwith a simple adapter.

The actual problem here is that the older data stay in the listview , and the same elements are added every 10 seconds.

The onPostExecute  is inside the JSONparse class:

```
private static final String TAG_OS = "istekler";
private static final String TAG_VER = "isim";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "istek";
private static final String TAG_API = "mesaj";

 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
            for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String isim = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                String mesaj = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String istek = c.getString(TAG_API);

                // Adding value HashMap key => value

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_VER, isim);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, mesaj);
                map.put(TAG_API, istek);

                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(user.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                        R.id.isim,R.id.mesaj, R.id.istek});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(user.this, "Parça: "+oslist.get(+position).get("istek"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

Comment: i think you need to clear your list. try to call oslist.clear() before oslist.add()

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day.   I feel so embarassed for being such a stupid :D

Comment: i put it as an answer so you can mark as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your code you just add new elements to your list. You should call oslist.clear() to remove the old data.